# How to create a simple Facebook Landing with an image?

Tags: facebook

How is it possible to create an simple Facebook landing page that just holds an image?

Should I create an Facebook app or is it possible with, some sort of Facebook language?

Something like this page: http://www.facebook.com/pages/FLOVT-Fik-2-eksamenssp%C3%B8rgsm%C3%A5l-om-kendte-men-dumpede-Se-sp%C3%B8rgsm%C3%A5lene-her/134656813218361

That just have an image.

Comment: Don't reask a closed question that you already posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231894/closed-closed-closed-closed

Comment: It is not the same qustion. This does nothing to do with RoR

Comment: You should probably read the Facebook help regarding pages, as far as I know this has little to nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I actually have read some of the facebook page readme. But I cant find any guide of to create a landing page with an simple image. I do think there is some markup language FBML. But there is something about pages cant use it there are created after the 1. Marts 2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FBML you are referring to has been deprecated and you can no longer use it for Facebook fan page tabs.  You now need to create an iframe fan page tab, and point it to a web page location on one of your servers somewhere.  It can be a very simple html page that just has an image.  You will also want to make sure the website you are hosting it on has an SSL certificate otherwise people that have enabled Facebook via SSL won't be able to see your fan page.

There is a good [walkthrough](https://www.facebook.com/notes/hyperarts-web-design/adding-an-iframe-application-to-your-facebook-fan-page-2011/10150145148215844) on how to set this all up, step by step.

Comment: Is SSL something the user has to activate or is it standard?

Comment: They currently have to turn it on, but Facebook prompts them occasionally to turn it on.  Plus, with Facebook, you never know, one day they will probably force it on for everyone with very little notice.

Comment: Do you know other good guides on facebook apps/iframe :)